# How to get a TortoiseSVN log of only one folder, but non-recursive

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a folder that I'd like to see the log of, but I only want to see the log of the files in this folder, not the subfolders.  Is there any way to do this in TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do a log on each file.